# XML parse with PHP / MySQL database Statements and import within mysql arabic letters date formatting

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, xml-parsing, arabic

Below is my data format in XML, from Oracle database which I am exporting to import with MySQL:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESULTS>
<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATID"><![CDATA[29]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATNAME"><![CDATA[Delivery Items]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATNAME_A"><![CDATA[توصيل المواد]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CB_DATE"><![CDATA[30-MAY-12]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATID"><![CDATA[30]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATNAME"><![CDATA[Important Numbers]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CLIENTCATNAME_A"><![CDATA[أرقام هامة]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CB_DATE"><![CDATA[30-MAY-12]]></COLUMN>
</ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

It contains Arabic words and Date in different format that expected by MySQL.

What will be the easiest way to import same with proper date format and arabic letters conversion to supported character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of MySQL server you are using?
For Arabic words to accommodate, set the charset for the table to "UTF-8".

For more reference on XML import check the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html